# Where can the red keycard spawn on Syntax Error?

Tags: payday-3

In the Syntax Error heist, you need a red keycard to access the AI control room. However, in my first run on this heist, we had an extremely difficult time finding a red keycard anywhere in the data center. Where can the red keycard spawn?

Answer (score 1):

I know of three spawn points, that are all little red boxes that appear empty or not. There is only one badge that spawn.

All of them are in the underground part of the map

```
    _ __ _ __ _
___|x|RA| |RB| |_
| ___________   x|
| ________|RC|   |__
|__   __ _ __ _____ |
 _|  |RE| |RD|___|_ |
| _______ ____  x___|
|_|     >_|   |___|
```

`RA`, `RB`, `RC`, `RD` and `RE` are the server rooms
`>` mark the escalator going down in the map

The `x` marks where you can find the red boxes that may contain the red badge:

- In the little hallway near the door to server room A
- Near where you have to bring the server to analyse them, on the left of the computer, against the wall. On the right if you are facing the vent.
- In the hallway on the right of the entrance to this whole map, just left of the glass door to the little room going up to the locked room needing the red keycard